# How do I copy and paste a command to a command block on Minecraft Xbox One?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Mojang recently released the Minecraft Better together update and I want to know if it is possible to copy and paste custom commands in Minecraft on Xbox One.

Comment: Seems really annoying but https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nGbTfel_VLw.  Unless you mean the actual text.  For that, I'd try using Xbox Smartglass (the Xbox app for phones).

Comment: No, he means text.

Comment: yes I am talking about the actual text. Specifically, I want to be able to use custom commands made my the red engineer and others, without spending an hour just typing it.

Comment: I can use the Xbox app on my phone, but after I paste it into the text box on my phone, I can't actually confirm the text because of how long all of the commands normally are

Comment: @CreeperAweMannnn if the part of the command you can read is right, it's not hard to assume you were able to paste the entire command correctly, right? Or am I missing your point?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is that you really cant, not without transfering back and forth to pc.

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible to copy and paste commands from command blocks on xbox one normally.

Answer (score 0):

Press the X button and the Down arrow key to copy

Answer (score -1):

if you have the xbox one in your windows 10 you can coppy it on your computer and paste it in your command block. when you open your command block on the xbox one it gives you a blank box to paste in on your computer while you are connected to it.